# Getting scanning function for Canon imageClass (MF220 Series) printer to work

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing, canon, scanner

I am almost about to sell my printer, but I want to try one more time since it was a enjoyable to use while I was still using Windows.

Has anyone managed to get the *scanner* for a Canon imageClass printer all-in-one to work in the linux system, or is it a lost case? If so there a scanner driver that I missed?

distro: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
printer: Personally I'm using Canon imageCLASS MF229dw
driver: I have the Canon UFR2 Printer Driver for Linux v3.31-1
status: I've been able to duplex print, with minor glitches. So far only scanning is not possible.

Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: There's a new version for your current driver: http://www.canon.ca/inetCA/en/serviceDetail?m=load&directLink=Y&mid=9540B009&type=D&opt=1

Answer (score 1):

I have a canon imageclass 227dw. Driver 350. Connected to my WIFI.  Like you, the printing works but not the scanner.
After trying many scanning programs, different solutions and even ubuntu distros, etc. I simply couldn't make it work. I kept getting the error message scanner not found or unable to make the connection.

Here is my "fix", which is just plain luck but works for me.

I bought a Brother dcp-1617nw because I do need a scanner, so I downloaded ALL the drivers from brother page, even the .386

then I run this in a terminal window:

`sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4`

after that, I installed each one of the .deb files just by double-clicking. I then tried to test the Brother scanner in a simple scan and... Voila! the canon scanner now works! ...now I have 2 scanners working.. lol

Why? How? I have no idea, but it worked for me.  Something that the Brother drivers install makes the canon scanner work.

After this, I did the exact same thing for all my other computers and it works flawlessly in each one of them.

***BTW, for me***, the ONLY way I can make the canon printer work is by going to localhost: 631 (cups)(works in firefox, not in chrome), deleting the preset canon printer and adding the first canon printer on the list.
****Also, for me*** the only way my canon printer can work, is by installing the drivers in a terminal by typing:  `sudo ./install.sh`  and then follow the instructions, when asked to register the printer I say No, then use the cups interface I told you before.

I hope this weird solution works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

The driver could be download from [Canon page](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html).
Then unzip and install the driver.

```
tar zxf linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken.tar.gz
./linux-UFRII-drv-v350-uken/install.sh
```

Tested on Xubuntu 16.04. The driver works for my Canon MF220 printer.
Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you @Lam! Successful install for network connected Canon MF220 with Debian Buster. Required manually setting printer IP address.